# File download getting canceled afte ~1GB of transfer

Tags: php, plesk

I have a 4GB file on my server that is served via PHP Script.

Sadly after transferring around 1GB the download is aborted and i get the following messages in the server Log:

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://www.domain.tld/files/?dir=downloads/Video/testvid
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: http://www.domain.tld/files/?dir=downloads/Video/testvid
```

I googled both errors but every suggestion so far didn't work or had to do with changing the chmod on some data plesk uses which will throw errors.

Anybody any ideas? - What exactly is going wrong?

I already tried that i put this in my apache &nginx Settings for http & https:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c> 
FcgidConnectTimeout 43200 
FcgidBusyTimeout 43200 
FcgidIOTimeout 43200 
FcgidMaxRequestLen 335544320 
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 20000 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you specifying the Content-length?

Comment: Check for fcgi timeouts like FcgidIOTimeout

Comment: I already tried that i put this in my apache &nginx Settings for http & https:


<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
 FcgidConnectTimeout 43200
 FcgidBusyTimeout 43200
 FcgidIOTimeout 43200
 FcgidMaxRequestLen 335544320
 FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 20000
</IfModule>